# X minutes left before

Tags: word-usage, usage

Do these sound fine instead of "It's five minutes to/before ten":

> There are five minutes left before ten.
>
> We/I have ten minutes before ten.

And if someone asks:

> How many minutes are left before ten?

Comment: All of them sound correct.

Comment: I have never heard nor seen a native English speaker use any of those expressions.

Comment: @RonalSole do these sound fine in a different context: "There are five minutes left before you have to hand it in ", "There are five minutes left before the class starts," "There are five minutes left before the police arrives."